# USB3.0 RAID 1 enclosure that can be connected to my new router

Tags: usb, nas, raid, drive-enclosure

I have wanted to set up a NAS for ages. I recently moved house and had to buy a [new fibre modem/router](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-5490/technical-specifications/). It has two USB 3.0 ports, and it'll be switched on all the time, so I figured it might be a low cost, low power way to get my NAS going.

I want my NAS to be RAID 1, so I was looking at enclosures like the ones suggested [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9851/how-can-i-use-two-usb-external-hard-drives-by-mirroring-both-like-raid-1) and [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9634/usb3-hub-that-can-handle-2-external-hard-drives-simultaneously/9651#9651). However, I'm a bit nervous about compatibility issues between the USB enclosure and the router. Do devices like these always work nicely together these days?

If I were plugging the enclosure into my PC, then I would feel confident that I could sort out any driver issues. But with the router's OS, I pretty much have to hope it just works, else I'm stuffed.

Thanks for any tips or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do devices like these always work nicely together these days?

This depends on the dual-bay enclosure that you buy, but most of them appear to the computer as a USB hub with either one or two [USB storage class devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class) attached to it.

With the enclosure that I have used before (Mediasonic ProRaid), there is a physical switch to select how the disks are used. When it is in RAID 0 or 1 mode, the PC can only see one drive which is the virtual disk created by the RAID. I have tested this enclosure with multiple operating systems and it seems to work as a plug & play USB drive, like any other USB hard drive or stick would.

Since your router does support USB storage, I expect that *most* USB RAID 1 enclosures will be detected by the router as a single drive.

Comment: Good information and link. The other concern is CPU grunt of the router. Apparently it has a 500 MHz dual-core, which seems on the weedy side to me. I'll do some speed tests with an ordinary USB HDD I have lying around. It would be a shame to throttle network performance with a CPU bottleneck. It looks like the price jump from RAID DAS to RAID NAS is not so enormous, and I guess the power consumption could be fairly similar too.